# Error response when publishing link and picture to Facebook Graph API /{page_id}/feed edge

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

We have an application configured in Facebook that we use to post to pages for many different users using the Graph API /{page_id}/feed edge. We have been using this edge for the last couple years and have recently encountered some issues publishing to pages using this edge under certain circumstances. The posts under question include link, picture, and message request parameters.  The link and the picture URLs point to content that we host.  The picture for the link is always in a png format.

Around 3/18/2014 we began to see a number of these posts fail when sending to various pages.  There are in total 13 pages we have failed to publish to at this time.  Since the date we began to see issues, we have successfully posted to other pages.  We stopped retrying any posts that failed before the 24th.  On the 24th we attempted to post to a 3 different pages, all failing the initial attempt and subsequent retries.

Today we began to see the posts that failed on the 24th trickle through to Facebook at about 1 per hour.  This would lead me to believe there was a throttling issue except the error response from Facebook did not indicate this and we are able to successfully publish to the pages if we do not include a picture request parameter.

I have checked our server logs to see if we were successfully processing requests for the pictures from the FB scraper for posts that failed, and they indicate that we are indeed successfully processing those requests (response code 200) and they tend to take anywhere from 100 - 1,000 milliseconds.

When the posts fail we receive an OAuthException with error code 386. The exception contains the message "An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later." Some testing has indicated that it is related to posts that include a link and a picture.  Just including the link allows the post to go through immediately.  Another interesting thing is we can post to the /{page_id}/photos/uploaded edge without any issues.  I have tested this using pictures ranging from ~100KB to ~1MB and this had no affect on the outcome.

I would also like to note that the URL for the picture is over HTTP not HTTPS.

Any thoughts as to what may be the cause of the posts failing and then trickling through slowly would be greatly appreciated.  I will append more information as it is acquired.

Comment: Hi sir did u fixed this issue i have the same pb :(

Comment: We did not find the exact cause of the problem.  It appears that it was related to one of the URLs we provided for a picture was rejected by Facebook which caused most of the failures.  Changing the URL we used for the pictures to a different URL got our posts through.  I do not know what procedure needs to be taken to have Facebook unblock our old URL or why it was blocked in the first place.